# MySQL Query conversion to HQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

Can someone please help me convert the following MySQL query into HQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(insert_datetime, '%Y%m%d') as onlyDate
FROM ticket 
WHERE 
DATE( insert_datetime ) = DATE( NOW() ) AND
status not in ( 1, 2, 6)
GROUP BY onlyDate;
```

In above query I am trying to get count of tickets for current day (only date not time) which must have specific status.

Entity Bean looks like as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ticket")
public class TicketBean implements IPersistable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long ticketId;
    private Integer status;
    private Date insertDatetime;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name="ticket_id")
    public Long getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(Long ticketId) {
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }

    @Column(name="insert_datetime")
    public Date getInsertDatetime() {
        return insertDatetime;
    }

    public void setInsertDatetime(Date insertDatetime) {
        this.insertDatetime = insertDatetime;
    }

    @Column(name="status")
    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your query portable I would omit the part `DATE_FORMAT(insert_datetime, '%Y%m%d')` and code the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(tb), tb.insertDatetime AS onlyDate
FROM TicketBean tb
WHERE 
    tb.insertDatetime = CURRENT_DATE AND
    tb.status not in (1, 2, 6)
GROUP BY onlyDate
```

You can format your date at server side using `DateFormatter`.

Please note that you can also use native database functions in `JPQL`. Majority of providers will not complain if you just write function call as it is. Since JPA 2.1 you can call it "nicely":

```
SELECT FUNCTION('DATE_FORMAT', tb.insertDatetime, '%Y%m%d') AS onlyDate
```